# This is my deceased Grandpa's patent. What exactly would this be used for?

Tags: us3099409

In reference to the patent: [US3099409](https://www.google.com/patents/US3099409)

Can anyone help me understand what the patent was for?

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on discovering your Grandfather's patent. This patent describes a device for winding coils used in electric motors. Many electric motors (even now) utilize cores made with ferro-magnetic material like iron or steel around which magnet wire is wound. Magnet wire is usually normal copper wire with a thin varnish insulation. Essentially you create a series of electromagnets that interact with permanent magnets or external coils to turn a shaft. Winding these coils by hand can be pretty tedious so an automated system would be very useful. This shows a typical rotor from a small electric motor that the patent would apply to.

[image]

Reading these sorts of questions is fun for me as I wonder if some day my grandchildren (should I be so lucky) will happen upon my patents...